# How to scrape HTML tables from a list of links

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some tables (election data) using the XML package. Browsing SO, I found out how to scrape a single url using:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.elecciones2011.gob.ar/paginas/paginas/dat99/DPR99999A.htm"
total <- readHTMLTable(url)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(total, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
df<-as.data.frame(total[[which.max(n.rows)]])
```

With the above code I get a nice enough result. I'm also able (with the readLines function and some tweaking) to get a vector with all the urls I want to scrape. Like this:

```
base_url <- "http://www.elecciones2011.gob.ar/paginas/paginas/"
urls <- paste(
  base_url,
  c(
    "dat02/DPR02999A", 
    "dat03/DPR03999A", 
    "dat04/DPR04999A", 
    "dat05/DPR05999A", 
    "dat06/DPR06999A", 
    "dat07/DPR07999A", 
    "dat08/DPR08999A", 
    "dat09/DPR09999A", 
    "dat10/DPR10999A", 
    "dat11/DPR11999A", 
    "dat12/DPR12999A", 
    "dat13/DPR13999A", 
    "dat14/DPR14999A", 
    "dat15/DPR15999A", 
    "dat16/DPR16999A", 
    "dat17/DPR17999A", 
    "dat18/DPR18999A", 
    "dat19/DPR19999A", 
    "dat20/DPR20999A", 
    "dat21/DPR21999A", 
    "dat22/DPR22999A", 
    "dat23/DPR23999A", 
    "dat24/DPR24999A"
  ),
  ".htm",
  sep = "" 
)
```

What I'd like to do is to create a function that runs the readHTMLTable function in all the urls and store the results in a vector or data frame (in one or many, whatever is easier). I'm quite new with R, and I'm particularly bad at functions. I tried something like...

```
tabla<- for (i in urls){
        readHTMLTable(urls)
        }
```

...but it's not even close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic approach, using a loop. This just wraps the code you supplied inside a `for`.

```
tabla <- list()
for(i in seq_along(urls))
{
    total <- readHTMLTable(urls[i])
    n.rows <- unlist(lapply(total, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
    tabla[[i]] <- as.data.frame(total[[which.max(n.rows)]])
}
```

A more elegant approach, using `lapply`. Now the code supplied is put inside a function, which is called for each url.

```
tabla <- lapply(urls, function(url) {
    total <- readHTMLTable(url)
    n.rows <- unlist(lapply(total, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
    as.data.frame(total[[which.max(n.rows)]])
})
```

Comment: tick the little tick, give Hong Ooi some points, and that'll flag this Q as answered....

Comment: There, I marked the the answer as accepted. i can´t give Hong Ooi point yet, I need a 15 point reputation myself :( Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using the `plyr` package.Note that this solution automatically extracts the list of links you are interested in from the page and then iterates through those links collecting all the tables you are interested in.

```
library(XML); library(plyr)

# PARSE WEBPAGE INTO DOC
url <- "http://www.elecciones2011.gob.ar/paginas/paginas/dat99/DPR99999A.htm"
doc <- htmlParse(url)

# EXTRACT LINKS OF INTEREST AND CREATE ABSOLUTE PATHS
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'divindex']//a", xmlGetAttr, 'href')
links <- gsub("..", 'http://www.elecciones2011.gob.ar/paginas/paginas', links, 
   fixed = T)

# EXTRACT TABLES OF INTEREST FROM LINKS
tables = llply(links, function(l) readHTMLTable(l)[[3]], .progress = 'text')
```