# Web Scraping (in R) - readHTMLTable error

Tags: r

I have a file called Schedule.csv, which is structured as follows:

```
URLs
http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=10&day=27&year=2015
http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=10&day=28&year=2015
```

I am trying to use the explanation provided in the following question to scrape the html tables but it isn't working: [How to scrape HTML tables from a list of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924409/how-to-scrape-html-tables-from-a-list-of-links)

My current code is as follows:

```
library(XML)
schedule<-read.csv("Schedule.csv")
stats <- list()
for(i in seq_along(schedule))
{
    print(i)
    total <- readHTMLTable(schedule[i])
    n.rows <- unlist(lapply(total, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
    stats[[i]] <- as.data.frame(total[[which.max(n.rows)]])
}
```

I get an error when I run this code as follows:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
```

If I manually type the URL's in a vector as per below I get exactly what I want when I run the readHTMLTable code.

```
schedule<-c("http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=10&day=27&year=2015","http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=10&day=28&year=2015")
```

Can someone please explain to me why the read.csv is not giving me a usable vector of information to input into the readHTMLTable function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read.csv` creates a data.frame in your `shcedule`. Then you want to access it by rows (`seq_along` and `schedule[i]` work along the columns of the data frame)

In your case you can do:

```
for (i in 1:nrow (schedule)) { 
    total <- readHTMLTable(schedule[i, 1])
```

as I understand you want the first column of your data.frame, change the `, 1]` or use column names otherwise.

Also notice that read.csv will read your first column as a **factor** so you may prefer to read it as a **character**:

```
schedule<-read.csv("Schedule.csv", as.is = TRUE)
```

An other alternative if your file has a unique column is to use `readLines` an then you can keep your loop as it was...

```
schedule<-readLines("Schedule.csv")
stats <- list()
for(i in seq_along(schedule))
{
    print(i)
    total <- readHTMLTable(schedule[i])
...
```

but be careful with the column names because they will be in the first element of your `schedule` vector

Comment: Awesome mate, this worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)